# Recursively find the sum of a number's digits w/ RegEx and w/o Eval()

Tags: javascript, regex, recursion

Can anyone suggest an implementation that avoids eval, hopefully uses regex,  and executes in 6 lines or less? Its a fun problem.

Input: `12 => 3`
Input: `235 => 10 => 1`

```
function baseNumber(n){
   var x =  eval(n.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=\d)/g, '$1+'))
   if(x>9){
     return baseNumber(x)
   } else {
     return x
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use regex (you could also do the same thing without regex and using split)

```
function baseNumber(n){
   if (n > 9)
      return baseNumber(n.toString().match(/(\d)/g).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + Number(b) }, 0))
   else
      return n;
}
```

The reduce does the summing up. The match returns the array of matches (i.e. digits)

If you want to handle decimals and negative numbers change the `if (n > 9)` check to `if (n.toString().length > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try casting `n` to `String` , utilizing `String.prototype.split()` , `String.prototype.replace()` , `Array.prototype.splice()` , `Number()` , `do.. while` loop

```js
function baseNumber(n) {     
  var x = String(n).replace(/[^\d]/g, "").split(""), y = 0;   
  do { y += Number(x.splice(0, 1)) } while (!!x.length);
  return y > 9 ? baseNumber(y) : y
}

console.log(baseNumber("abc12"), baseNumber("def235"))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
var input = 235;
while(input > 9) input  = String(input).match(/[\d]/g).reduce(function(sum, currentValue) { 
    return sum + parseInt(currentValue);
}, 0);
console.log(input);
```